# Passing an error to a component

Tags: vue.js

I have an `AddComment.vue` component which has a form, on submit it hits a laravel api endpoint where validation happens. If validation fails I want to show the errors in `AddComment.vue`. How can return the `error.response` object to `AddComment.vue`? Currently, I can see 'fired' in the console when I want to be logging the error. Where am I going wrong any help would be greatly appreciated

AddComponent.vue

```
methods: {
    addComment() {
        this.$store.dispatch('addComment', {
            name: this.name,
            email: this.email,
            body: this.body
        })
        .then(response => {
            this.$router.push({ name: 'home' })
            console.log('fired')
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    },
}
```

store.js

```
actions: {
    addComment(context, comment) {
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            axios.post('/comments', {
                name: comment.name,
                email: comment.email,
                body: comment.body,
                approved: false
            })
            .then(response => {
                context.commit('addComment', response.data)
                resolve(response)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error)
            })
        });
    },
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The catch() block only gets called if the Laravel backend throws an error. So if you are returning a normal status code of 2xx then axios always calls the .then() part. In that case, you have to resolve the error message yourself.

Try something like this in your backend route (it will return an error):

```
return response()->toJson([
    'message' => 'error message',
], 500);
```

And see if this responds with an actual error in you vuejs application.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. If I `console.log(error.response)` in the catch of the addComment action I get the correct json so the endpoint is working ok. I think the problem is somehow passing the response to the `AddComment.vue` component.

Comment: Ah okay, i think what is missing here is the return expression in your store.js. Add "return new Promise..." to the beginning of your addComment function